# Sending text plus the contents of a file to standard input, without using temporary files

Tags: linux, unix, scripting

We know that it's simple to send the contents of a text file, `file.txt`, to a script that reads from standard input:

```
the_script < file.txt
```

Supposed that I'd like to do the same thing as above, except I have an extra line of text I'd like to send to the script *followed* by the contents of the file?  Surely there must be a better way than this:

```
echo "Here is an extra line of text" > temp1
cat temp1 file.txt > temp2
the_script < temp2
```

Can this be accomplished without creating any temporary files at all?

Comment: You should upvote answers that work, not just comment below them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on cdarke's answer to make it readable left-to-right:

```
echo "Extra line" | cat - file.txt | the_script
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this.  Modern shells (Bash and ksh93) have a feature to support reading a single value from stdin, known as a *here string*:

```
cat - file.txt <<< "Extra line"|the_script
```

The first argument of `cat` is a hyphen `-` which reads from standard-input.  The here string follows the `<<<` notation.

Answer (score 0):

This should do in `bash`:

```
{ echo "Here is an extra line of text"; cat file.txt; } < the_script
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great.  Suppose `the_script` has a single optional flag, i.e. `the_script --option`.  How would that fit into this example?

Comment: You can just add the flag after `the_script`, like so: `{ echo "Here is an extra line of text"; cat file.txt; } < the_script --option`